# How to compress Image byte size and convert it to WEBP in Android using zetbaitsu/Compressor

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

Ive been trying to reverse engineer this project to understand more about zetbaitsu's [Image Compression](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) on github. Sad thing is, the code wont even compile. And I cant understand some of the code since its written in Java and not Kotlin.

Its been days since I started looking for a clear and straight to the point tutorial that tells how to compress image size. Can anyone tell me how I can compress Image file size and format.

If you have another way, please do include it bellow.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mainBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var imageUri: Uri

    // For Image Compression
    private lateinit var actualImageFile: File
    private lateinit var compressedImageFile: File

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        fetchDataInFirebaseDatabase()
        buttonFunctions()

    }

    class CardView(val text: String, val imageUrl: String, val dataUuid: String) {
        constructor(): this("", "", "")
    }

    class MainAdapter(val cardView: ArrayList<CardView>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {
        class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cardview_main, parent, false)
            return CustomViewHolder(view)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.view.apply {
                cardView_textView.text = cardView[position].text
                Picasso.get().load(cardView[position].imageUrl).into(holder.view.cardView_imageView)
            }
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return cardView.count()
        }
    }

    private fun fetchDataInFirebaseDatabase() {
        val databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/")
        val cardView = ArrayList<CardView>()
        val mainAdapter = MainAdapter(cardView)
        databaseRef.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                snapshot.children.forEach {
                    val dataValue = it.getValue(CardView::class.java)
                    if (dataValue != null) cardView.add(dataValue)
                    mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                Log.d("MainFragment", "Number of children ${snapshot.key} = ${snapshot.childrenCount}")
            }
            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {}
            override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                snapshot.children.forEach {
                    mainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {}
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
        })
        mainBinding.activityMainGridRecyclerView.adapter = mainAdapter
    }

    private fun buttonFunctions() {
        mainBinding.apply {

            // Upload Text & Image in Firebase
            activityMainUploadButton.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Uploading Data...")
                //storeDataInFirebaseDatabase()
                storeImageInFirebaseStorage()
            }

            // Choose an image in album
            activityMainSelectPhotoButton.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Selecting Image...")
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
            }
        }
    }

    // Apply chosen image as button background
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Image Selected")
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
            mainBinding.activityMainSelectPhotoButton.apply {
                text = ""
                setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable(bitmap))
            }
        }
    }

    private var randomUUID: String? = null
    private fun storeImageInFirebaseStorage() {
        randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/FirebaseGridView/$randomUUID/")
        storageRef.putFile(imageUri) // Store image URI in Firebase Storage
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Image successfully stored in Firebase Storage")
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Image size: ${it.metadata!!.sizeBytes}bytes / ${it.metadata!!.sizeBytes / 1000}kb")
                storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { // Get the image URL from Firebase Storage
                    storeDataInFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
                }
                return@addOnSuccessListener

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Image failed to store in Firebase Storage")
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }
    }

    // Stores data of CardView text/imageUrl/UUID in Firebase Database
    private fun storeDataInFirebaseDatabase(imageUrl: String) {
        val editText = mainBinding.activityMainInputEditText.text.toString()
        val cardView = CardView(editText, imageUrl, randomUUID!!)
        val databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FirebaseGridView/$randomUUID/")

        // Upload Data in FirebaseGridView/$randomUUID/ directory with the format/value of cardView
        databaseRef.setValue(cardView)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Data successfully stored in Firebase Database")
                Log.d("MainActivity", "\n \n Data Text: ${cardView.text} \n Data UUID: ${cardView.  dataUuid} \n Image URL: ${cardView.imageUrl}")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data is stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addOnSuccessListener

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Data failed to be stored in Firebase Database")
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data failed to store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addOnFailureListener
            }
    }
}
```

This is my failed attempt at trying to use Image Compress.

```
// TODO Compress Image file here
    private fun customCompressImage() {
        actualImageFile.let { imageFile ->
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                compressedImageFile = Compressor.compress(this@MainActivity, imageFile) {
                    //resolution(int)
                    quality(40)
                    format(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                    size(1_090_000) // 1mb
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setCompressedImage() {
        compressedImageFile.let {

        }
    }
```

Comment: where do you call `customCompressImage`? Android has built in convertor for this purposes, but without option to set output file size `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathToOutputFile); bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, out); out.close();` where `bitmap` is representing jpeg file (converted with `BitmapFactory`)

Comment: Hi @snachmsm `customeCompressImage` is not yet called because its not a "complete" code.

Comment: @snachmsm Do you have any resource regarding this built in converter. I cant find anything clear that uses kotlin.

Comment: well, I have documentation links... [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/BitmapFactory) and [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/Bitmap). Kotlin is just a language, you can switch in docs site to this lang (to the right, on top of every doc site)